# Should (IPv6) multicast subscribers send report to query?

Tags: ipv6, multicast

I am waking through [RFC3810](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3810#section-5.1) and playing with MLDv2.
From that RFC I thought when anyone send query for group `::` (all groups) and send it to address `ff02::1` all subscribers on segment should send its reports within **m**aximum **r**esponse **d**elay. So I created and sent that query using scapy:

`sendp(Ether()/IPv6(dst='ff02::1')/IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop(options=[RouterAlert()])/ICMPv6MLQuery2(mladdr="::", mrd=1000, QRV=2, QQIC=60) ,iface="USB-Eth", loop=0, inter=0)`

I have win10 pc, Linux pc and Mikrotik all of them subscribed to group ff16::fe connected to same Lan (through dumb switch). I can see all of them sent correct listener report but none of those devices responds to my query. No matter if I send it from Linux or Win.

I compared my packet with some capture I found on the net and it differs only in source link local addr and check sums.

Is my expectation wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumby me...

Of course **every listener must reply to query**. But listener must discard query with hop limit different than 1.

Here is the correct scapy command:

`sendp(Ether()/IPv6(dst='ff02::1',hlim=1)/IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop(options=[RouterAlert()])/ICMPv6MLQuery2(mladdr="::", mrd=10000, QRV=2, QQIC=125) ,iface='enp1s0', loop=0, inter=0)`

And [here](https://github.com/edzius/mcquery) is some handy utility which when called like this `sudo ./mcquery -i enp1s0 mld:2` sends identical query.